# Problems with mouse detection

Tags: mouse

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a new HDD and I'm having a weird problem with my mouse.

When I start the computer its works fine but after a while I can´t click in the desktop, but in the upper and lateral menu it's continues working fine (I can open any program in this menus, shutdown the computer, etc..)

The mouse is a Mad Catz R.A.T. 5, and I've modified Xorg.conf to avoid the compatibility problems with Ubuntu. 
In Windows the mouse works fine too.